Problem with sending e-mail using Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() method
The email is sent after the Case is created via Email-to-Case. When sending an email using this method the email is sent to the user and to the user who is given as whoId (documentation here. Does anyone know why this is happening? The user whoId should not receive any email. Below is code.
private static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createEmailMessage(Case newCase, Id emailTemplateId, Id orgWideEmailAddressId) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mailMessage = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(emailTemplateId, newCase.CreatedById, newCase.Id);
    mailMessage.setToAddresses(new List<String>{
            newCase.SuppliedEmail
    });
    mailMessage.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailAddressId);
    mailMessage.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mailMessage.setUseSignature(false);

    return mailMessage;
}

There is no auto-response rule set on the Sandbox.

Have you tried running this code on it's own via exec anonymous? That method does not send an email, so I suspect the code calling createEmailMessage is taking the result of the method call and sending it out somehow

What do you mean by "sent to the user and to the user who is given as whoId"?  Which two users are these?  Where are you setting WhoId?  Your documentation link is broken.  Please [edit] your post to include these details and the correct link.
